# Is it possible to create an UIAlertView without any buttons?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I need help with `UIAlertView` :-). Currently I have an `UIAlertView` showing up when the user shakes the device using the `-(void)motionEnded:` function. I want to make the alert view disappear after 0.5 seconds using a `NSTimer` so I don't need any button at the bottom of the alert view to dismiss it. Is there a way to create an UIAlertView without any button? [A way to remove the space with the arrow in the image below?]

Here's the code:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    resetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset!"
                                            message:nil
                                           delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [resetAlert show];

    alertHideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.5 target:self selector:@selector(dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    self.label.text = @"0";
    numero = 0;
    [self.label2 setHidden:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you only want to show an alert for less than a second you probably shouldn't even use one at all.

Comment: Yup but I want to tell the user that an operation in being made in an "Apple style" like when you shake to undo typing ^^,

Comment: I understand that, but if the alert is displayed for half a second, the users couldn't possibly read the message you're displaying in time.

Comment: Mhmm that's true... if this won't work well I'll try an other way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Try the following: [iToast](http://code.google.com/p/toast-notifications-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own view. Show and hide/close it as per your requirement, timers etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if having the `NSTimer` with a multiple argument selector is correct. I add this method:

```
-(void)dismissAlertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView {
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}
```

and replace your `NSTimer` with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) withObject:resetAlert afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: While, I agree with your observation about multiple argument selectors, I'd point out that (a) he can use `NSTimer` if he'd like (either have the method refer to the `resetAlert` ivar, which he's probably doing now, or pass the `UIAlertView` in `userInfo`); but that (b) that wasn't the question. He's asking how to get the `UIAlertView` without buttons and without the space at the bottom where buttons go. Mike and Anoop have hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll check that too :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know removing the space entirely is not possible.

However... here are some things you may want to try;

### Adding top padding

Add a few newlines to get top padding: `initWithTitle:@"\n\nConfiguring Preferences...`

[image: Top Padding Example]
<sub>(source: [iosdevelopertips.com](http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/alert2-204x300.png))</sub>

### Adding a spinner

Add a UIActivityIndicatorView to the UIAlertView

`alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Configuring Preferences\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];`

`[alert show];`

`UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];`

Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert

`indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);`

`[indicator startAnimating];`

`[alert addSubview:indicator];`

[image: Indicator Example]
<sub>(source: [iosdevelopertips.com](http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/alert3-204x300.png))</sub>

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the alert simply by calling the delegate method after 5 sec

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: The question is not now to dismiss the alert, but rather how to get rid of the gap below the text of the message.

Comment: Mhmm that's not what I wanted to know :-S, thank you anyway u.u